# Least-squares over the unit simplex

Tags: optimization, convex-optimization, least-squares, constraints, quadratic-programming

I am interested in the non-negative least squares problem subject to one equality constraint

$$\begin{array}{ll} \text{minimize} & \| \mathrm A \mathrm x - \mathrm b \|_2^2\\ \text{subject to} & \mathrm 1_n^T \mathrm x = 1\\ & \mathrm x \geq 0_n\end{array}$$

Each element of vector $\mathrm x$ is non-negative and they sum to one. Is there any closed solution or fast iterative method? The dimension of $\mathrm x$ is not very big, but I need a fast method as this optimization is to be executed many times for different sub-sampled data sets.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one approach that works if $A$ is invertible:

You are projecting $b$ onto the convex set $A \Sigma$, where $\Sigma = \{ x | x_k \ge 0, \sum_k x_k = 1\}$.

Let $C = \operatorname{co} \{ A e_k \}_k$, then the problem becomes
one of finding the closest point $c\in C$ to $b$. Then the solution
is $x=A^{-1} c$.

I am not current, but an efficient algorithm for solving this problem is
given in
Wolfe, P. ,Finding the Nearest Point in a Polytope, Mathematical Programming, Vol. 11, pp. 128–149,1976.

If $A$ is not invertible, one needs to solve $Ax = c$ to obtain a solution.

Comment: Why assume that $\mathrm A$ is square?

Comment: @RodrigodeAzevedo: If $A$ is not square, it is not invertible, so one needs to solve $Ax=c$ after solving the closest point problem.

Comment: Let me get this straight. Let's say I can project $ b $ into the simplex. Namely $ c = \operatorname{Proj}_{\mathcal{S}} \left( b \right) $ where $ \mathcal{S} $ is the Unit Simplex. Then all needed is to solve $ \hat{x} = \arg \min_{x} \left\| A x - c \right\|_{2}^{2} $?

Comment: @Royi: No. There is much less content to my answer than you are thinking. You need to project $b$ onto $C$ then all I am saying is that you can recover a suitable $x$ by inverting.

Comment: I wrote least squares in case $ A $ isn't invertible.

Comment: @Royi: $C$ is not the unit simplex.

Comment: @Royi: I'm not sure what you are asking. It is defined in the second paragraph as the convex hull of the columns of $A$.

Comment: Let's say I have an operator to project on the Unit Simplex (The set the OP wanted the solution to be in) and a Linear system Solver. How can I use them to solve using your method (I know how to do it using Projected Gradient Descent)? Thank You.

Comment: @Royi: You could try the Wolfe algorithm mentioned in the answer.

Comment: I thought what you described was finding the closest point on the range of $ A $ to the projection of $ b $ on the Unit simplex. I guess I miss understood.

Comment: The problem is to find the closest point to $b$ in the polytope described by $A e_k$, where $e_k$ are the standard unit vectors.